# Hybrid content encryption for multiple authorized users (FE and BE)

Tags: rest, encryption, rsa, backend, private-key

At the moment I want to implement a method that stores certain data server-side only encrypted. For this procedure is provided that each authorized user receives a private key, with which he can store and read encrypted data. Now it is so that several authorized persons are allowed to look at the same encrypted content. This means that if person A stores data encrypted with his private key, person B (if authorized) can also read this data with his private key.

**The idea of ​​implementation:**
For all authorized persons, a single symmetric key is generated on the server side. The key is used to encrypt and decrypt plain text data. Now, for each individual claimant, a key pair is generated (public and private). With the public key, the symmetric key is encrypted and stored for the user and there are several of these asymmetrically encrypted symmetric keys on the server. The private key is given to the user (as a file download, HTTPS), which later can be used to decrypt the encrypted symmetric key. Therefore He can upload his private key before writing or reading encrypted data, in a web application (client side) and send it to the server. The Server uses the private Key to encrypt the content of the user and save it, or decrypt older content and send it in plain text to the user.

My problem now is that the weak point is the server, where the private key of the user must first be sent to encrypt and decrypt. There might be someone with access this private key secretly intercept and save.

**My question now:** Is there an alternative to the approach or does one have to do so if he wants to implement such a procedure? It is important that the data is stored only encrypted. And also this must be implemented with a client web-application and a backend.

Comment: The private key is called private key for a reason. The server must never see it. Encryption and decryption have to happen on the client, such that the server only ever sees ciphertext, encrypted symmetric keys, and plain *public* keys. [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) has methods for generating symmetric and asymmetric keys and also for wrapping and unwrapping them.

Comment: Thats true if you want to encrypt data for one person. But how you do this for multiple persons, so they can access the same encrypted content, with different keys? In this procedure you encrypt the content with one key of a user (doesnt matter who, just one who is allowed to) and grant write/read access for multiple persons. When generating the keyPair, you would have to send the plain text (!) symmetric key to the clients, so they can generate their pair localy.

Comment: Again, the key pairs and symmetric keys must be generated on the client if you want any kind of confidentiality. Clients send ciphertext and N encrypted copies of the symmetric key (encrypted with each public key of the N recipients). That's pretty much what PGP does.

Comment: Ok now i got the idea you mean and it sounds like a good solution for my problem. I will try it out with the master generating the keys on his client (with the public keys of the users) and also handling the encryption/decryption on the clients. Thx for you help